# .htaccess to redirect index.* and rewrite the url into a query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently trying to use two rewrite rules in the .htaccess file in the /sub/ folder of my website. One is a redirect to remove the index.php, index.html, etc. at the end of the url e.g. /sub/index.php -> /sub/:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule index.* %1/ [r=301,L]
```

The other is to rewrite the url for php to get the query string e.g. /sub/testing-testing -> /sub/index.php?field=testing-testing:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?command_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

These seem to work without a problem on their own but I just can't figure out how to get them to work together.

I can see how it might be going wrong with the second rule because the first one is matching "index(...)" so I've tried different variations of these but I keep ending up with either endless redirect loops or being redirected back into the root of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match against the actual request, and not the URI when removing the `index.php`. The reason why the 2 rules won't work together is because mod_rewrite keeps looping through all the rules until the URI stops changing. The 2nd rule rewrites the URI to `index.php`, the first rule matches it and removes it, then the 2nd rule rewrites it back, etc.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.(php|html?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Then you should be able to leave the second rule as is.